# how to hide post content on home page (wordpress)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress to build my new site but I don't want my theme to display the post's content on my home page just the thumbnail picture and title.

I use the grid option.

**Index.php**: I see these 2 codes:

```
<?php if(get_theme_mod('fcs_home_layout') == 'grid') : ?>
```

---

```
<?php get_template_part('content'); ?>


content.php:
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<div class="post-header">

    <?php if(!get_theme_mod('fcs_post_cat')) : ?>
    <span class="cat"><?php the_category(' '); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_single()) : ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>


</div>

<?php if(get_theme_mod('fcs_post_comment_link') && get_theme_mod('fcs_post_share') && get_theme_mod('fcs_post_share_author')) : else : ?>   
<div class="post-share">

    <?php if(!get_theme_mod('fcs_post_date')) : ?>
    <div class="post-share-box postdate">
        <?php the_time( get_option('date_format') ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(!get_theme_mod('fcs_post_comment_link')) : ?>
    <div class="post-share-box share-comments">
        <?php comments_popup_link( '<span>0</span> Comments', '<span>1</span> Comment', '<span>%</span> Comments', '', ''); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(!get_theme_mod('fcs_post_share')) : ?>
    <div class="post-share-box share-buttons">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/home?status=Check%20out%20this%20article:%20<?php print findcools_social_title( get_the_title() ); ?>%20-%20<?php echo urlencode(the_permalink()); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <?php $pin_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>
        <a data-pin-do="skipLink" target="_blank" href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&media=<?php echo $pin_image; ?>&description=<?php the_title(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(!get_theme_mod('fcs_post_share_author')) : ?>
    <div class="post-share-box share-author">
        <span><?php _e( 'By', 'findcools' ); ?></span> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <?php if(!get_theme_mod('fcs_post_thumb')) : ?>
    <div class="post-img">
        <?php if(is_single()) : ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('findcools-full-thumb'); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('findcools-full-thumb'); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<div class="post-entry">

    <?php if(is_single()) : ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php if(get_theme_mod('fcs_post_summary') == 'excerpt') : ?>

            <p><?php echo fcs_string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), 80); ?>&hellip;</p>
            <p><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" class="more-link"><span class="more-button"><?php _e( 'Continue Reading', 'findcools' ); ?></span></a>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php the_content(__('Continue Reading<span class="more-line"></span>', 'findcools')); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>

    <?php if(!get_theme_mod('fcs_post_tags')) : ?>
    <?php if(is_single()) : ?>
    <?php if(has_tag()) : ?>
        <div class="post-tags">
            <?php the_tags("",""); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<?php if(!get_theme_mod('fcs_post_author')) : ?>
<?php if(is_single()) : ?>
    <?php get_template_part('inc/templates/about_author'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(!get_theme_mod('fcs_post_related')) : ?>
<?php if(is_single()) : ?>
    <?php get_template_part('inc/templates/related_posts'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php comments_template( '', true );  ?>
```

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: Are you using template for homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the is_page_template() function to make a conditional for that section. For you situation, on this template try using if (!is_page_template('name of home page template')) {code for post content}